# Issue regading custom form

Tags: modal-dialogs

https://wineshipinsure.com/newdrupal/ex81/helloform

I have been using the custom form  and followed all the process for creating the custom form but my form is not working and every time getting page not found issue.

Below I share the code for custom form

```
  ex81.hello_form:
  path: 'ex81/helloform'
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\ex81\Form\HelloForm'
    _title: 'Simple custom form example'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

HelloForm.php

```php
<?php
namespace Drupal\ex81\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * HelloForm controller.
 */
class HelloForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * Returns a unique string identifying the form.
   *
   * The returned ID should be a unique string that can be a valid PHP function
   * name, since it's used in hook implementation names such as
   * hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
   *
   * @return string
   *   The unique string identifying the form.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'ex81_hello_form';
  }

  /**
   * Form constructor.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The form structure.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['description'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('Please enter the title and accept the terms of use of the site.'),
    ];

    $form['title'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Enter the title of the book. Note that the title must be at least 10 characters in length.'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['accept'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => $this
        ->t('I accept the terms of use of the site'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Please read and accept the terms of use'),
    ];

    // Group submit handlers in an actions element with a key of "actions" so
    // that it gets styled correctly, and so that other modules may add actions
    // to the form. This is not required, but is convention.
    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    // Add a submit button that handles the submission of the form.
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;

  }

  /**
   * Validate the title and the checkbox of the form.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   The form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The form state.
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);

    $title = $form_state->getValue('title');
    $accept = $form_state->getValue('accept');

    if (strlen($title) < 10) {
      // Set an error for the form element with a key of "title".
      $form_state->setErrorByName('title', $this->t('The title must be at least 10 characters long.'));
    }

    if (empty($accept)) {
      // Set an error for the form element with a key of "accept".
      $form_state->setErrorByName('accept', $this->t('You must accept the terms of use to continue'));
    }

  }

  /**
   * Form submission handler.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // Display the results
    // Call the Static Service Container wrapper
    // We should inject the messenger service, but its beyond the scope
    // of this example.
    $messenger = \Drupal::messenger();
    $messenger->addMessage('Title: ' . $form_state->getValue('title'));
    $messenger->addMessage('Accept: ' . $form_state->getValue('accept'));

    // Redirect to home.
    $form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
  }

}
```

If anyone finds the solution please let me know asap....

Answer (score 0):

Indenting is very important in .yml files. Yours is incorrect. You need to change this:

```
  ex81.hello_form:
  path: 'ex81/helloform'
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\ex81\Form\HelloForm'
    _title: 'Simple custom form example'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

To this

```
ex81.hello_form:
  path: 'ex81/helloform'
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\ex81\Form\HelloForm'
    _title: 'Simple custom form example'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: I don't understand what you have changed in your code????

Comment: The indentation. The number of spaces matters in .yml